# Gorm relationship and issues

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I was creating my first-ever rest API in golang with fiber and form. I wanted to create a model that had a slice of strings, but gorm does not allow me to do so. SO, the next thing I tried was to use a map, hoping that it will be easily converted to JSON and saved to my postgres instance. But the same, gorm does not support maps. So, I created another struct into which I put all the data in a not-so-elegant way, where I made a single string value for each possible string I can save, and then I embedded this struct into the other. But now the compiler's complaints that I have to save a primary key into it, and not raw json given from the request. I am a bit overwhelmed by now

If someone knows I way that I can use to save all the data I need into the way that respects my requirements (slice of string, easy to parse when I read from the database), and to finish this CRUD app, I would really be thankful for that. thank you a lot

Comment: Hey man, can you explain better your request? It's hard to help you without any code snippets.

Comment: Did you consider using [pq.StringArray](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#StringArray)?